# NestJS: the function of cronJob is not working

Tags: cron, nestjs, scheduler

I want to set callback function to print 'hello' at 2023/07/15 20:50 P.M (KST).
So, I set my cronJob and added to scheduleRegistry. But it was not working.
Below codes are what I typed.

```
// AppModule.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TasksModule } from './tasks/tasks.module';

@Module({
  imports: [TasksModule],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```
// TasksModule.ts
import { Module, OnApplicationBootstrap } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TasksService } from './tasks.service';
import { ScheduleModule } from '@nestjs/schedule';

@Module({
  imports: [ScheduleModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [TasksService],
})
export class TasksModule implements OnApplicationBootstrap {
  constructor(private readonly tasksService: TasksService) {}

  async onApplicationBootstrap() {
    await this.tasksService.addCronJob();
    await this.tasksService.getCronJobs();
  }
}
```

```
// TasksService.ts
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SchedulerRegistry } from '@nestjs/schedule';
import { CronJob } from 'cron';

@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
  constructor(private schedulerRegisry: SchedulerRegistry) {}

  private logger = new Logger();
  async addCronJob() {
    const job = new CronJob(
      '0 50 20 15 7 *',
      () => this.logger.warn('printed'),
      null,
      false,
      'Asia/Seoul',
      null,
      false,
      540,
    );

    this.schedulerRegisry.addCronJob('test', job);
    job.start();
  }

  async getCronJobs() {
    console.log(this.schedulerRegisry.getCronJobs());
  }
}
```

please let me know why that was not working... :(